# How do I get two status-bar clocks with different timezones?

Tags: macos, timezone, clock

I'd like to have one clock in my status bar set to the same timezone as my servers.  I've found three applications that will allow me to add another clock:

- [Day-O](http://shauninman.com/archive/2011/10/20/day_o_mac_menu_bar_clock)
- [MenuCalendarClock](http://www.objectpark.net/mcc.html)
- [iClock](http://plumamazing.com/mac/iclock)

but they all use the system time (which I'd like to keep as-is).  Are there any applications that allow timezone-munging inside the app, or will I need to write this myself?

Comment: Are you certain this isn't supported natively? I doubt you will have to install a 3rd party application for something so simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lovers clock might be the one you are looking for

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26202/loversclock

Comment: Are you in some way affiliated?

Comment: While it's hardly the prettiest thing I've seen, this does exactly what I want, and it's GPLed.  Thanks!

Comment: Lovers works, but it does NOT work with the new "dark" menubar in OSX. Whereas mclock mentioned by @Ioannis below does adjust its text color. (https://github.com/palaniraja/mclock)

Comment: download from the link no longer functional.

Comment: Not only won't it download, the MacUpdate page says "LoversClock has been discontinued".

Answer (score 19):

Status clock is free, and available from the mac app store:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/status-clock/id552792489?mt=12

Worth a look too: https://github.com/palaniraja/mclock

Note: Loversclock, mentioned in another post, didn't download.

Comment: mclock is also free. You can download the binary from github. You can pay if you want by downloading it from app store.

Comment: made an account just to upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

I would also really like to display multiple times in my menu bar, but I'm not able to find anything like that either. I landed on [Clocker](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clocker-menubar-world-clock/id1056643111?mt=12). It's free and you can easily assign a keyboard shortcut which is really nice.

Comment: Yes! This is a very nice, free solution.

Comment: This is by far the best solution I came across. Thanks for sharing Sam.

Comment: It's also open source with MIT License: https://github.com/n0shake/Clocker

Answer (score 15):

There is a free option. Install [xbar](https://github.com/matryer/xbar) and then the World Clock plugin from:

https://xbarapp.com/docs/plugins/Time.html

[image]

Comment: Hey, that's now called xbar. (see https://xbarapp.com)

Answer (score 3):

Would having a menubar clock that displays other timezones in a drop-down menu work? I find [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) works for me for seeing other timezones easily, albeit not as easily as having the time in the timezone you want shown right there. It's commercial software, but there are similar open source project out there. Maybe one of them does the "other timezones in the dropdown" thing?

Comment: It's ok, but not ideal.  I'll take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in iStat now, at least on macOS.
Example included;

[image: iStat time display]

Comment: While correct, it would be helpful if the steps needed to achieve this were included in your answer. BTW, "at least on macOS" - this feels rather irrelevant since we are on the Apple SE.

Answer (score -2):

World time widget

Try this app